# How to create layouts or view dynamically?

Tags: android

I am building an Android app that has one of the features of clock app.I want to create a new view or layout on click of a button just like the one in case of clock app . How to achieve this?
[![Clock Application
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw6py.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw6py.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add dynamical layout in a simple way:

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Name");
lm.addView(tv);
```

alternately you can create a Recyclerview and add element dynamicaly.